# Can I drill into this retaining wall?

Tags: walls

I’ve got a grey brick like concrete retaining wall in my partly submerged garage. I want to drill screws into this for installing shelves/hand hooks etc. Is this ok to do? I’ve just bought the house and it seems strange to me that the previous owners haven’t drilled into this at all so I’m a little wary. Thanks.

Comment: "Grey brick like" isn't sufficiently detailed for a responsible answer. CMU block? An image would be ideal.

Comment: A retaining wall is built to hold back soil. As shelving weight increases, the wall's soil restraining capacity decreases. A weed wacker and some Christmas decorations could be fine if the shelving can be adequately anchored to the wall. Bags of sand? Probably not a good idea. It's wise when constructing such things to make them "light duty" so that 20 years from now somebody cannot ignorantly pile on the bags of sand.

Comment: You probably mean "partly below grade."